# How to use r to repeat a vector of sequence in descending and increasing order alternately?

Tags: r, vector, repeat

I am new to R. I need to create a vector of length 37 with elements repeating the following pattern:
0.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  1.5,  1.5, ... , 2.5, 2.5, 3.0,  3.0,  2.5,  2.5,  2.0,  2.0, ..., 0.5, 0.5, 0.0,  0.0, 0.5, 0.5, ...
The problem is, after creating the sequence, I do not know how to repeat it in the descending and increasing order alternately. Here is my code:

```
rep(seq(0.0,3.0,by = 0.5), each = 2, length = 37)
```

which only repeats the sequence in the general order. What should I supplement in my code to create a vector as required? Hope someone can help me solve this. Thank you so much!

Comment: What out put you want ?

Comment: If `r` is the output from your example, something like `rep(c(r, rev(r)), n)` should work, but I'm unclear exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: My expected output is to use r to create a vector of length 37 with elements repeating the following pattern: 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.5, ... , 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, ..., 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, ...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Here's the shortest I can do:

```
rep(rep(c(0:6,5:1)/2,e=2),l=37)


 [1] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0
[19] 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5
[37] 3.0
```

---

I'm curious to see a better way than this:

```
a <- rep(seq(0.0,3.0,by = 0.5), each = 2)    # go up
b <- rev(a[3:12])                            # go down, w/o ends
c <- c(a,b)                                  # combine
rep(c, length.out = 37)                      # repeat for 37 elements

 [1] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0
[10] 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0
[19] 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5
[28] 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5
[37] 3.0
```

Comment: Just had the same idea, you could say more concisely `rep(seq.int(0.0, 3.0, by=0.5) |> {\(.) c(., rev(.))}(), e=2, l=37)`.

Comment: Edited with shorter alternative: `rep(rep(c(0:6,5:1)/2,e=2),l=37)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
f <- function(length.out) {
  b = c(0, rep(seq(0.5, 2.5, 0.5), each=2), 3.0)
  n=ceiling(length.out-2)/10
  c(0, rep(c(b, rev(b)),n), 0)[1:length.out]
}
```

Now, just call the function, passing your desired length:

```
f(37)

 [1] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0
[30] 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0


f(246)


  [1] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5
 [29] 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5
 [57] 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5
 [85] 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5
[113] 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5
[141] 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5
[169] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5
[197] 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5
[225] 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0
```

Now, call the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rep(c(seq(0.0,3.0,by = 0.5),rep(seq(2.5,0.5,by = -0.5))), each = 2, length = 37)
```

Comment: The sequence needs to be repeated without ends, yours is not quite true

Comment: Try this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
mySeq <- seq(0.5,3.0,by = 0.5)

rep(c(0, mySeq, sort(mySeq[-6], decreasing = TRUE)), each = 2, length = 37)
```